# Phrase from the fairy tale

Tags: idioms

Could somebody explain me what it means: "They knocked the hard ground into soft, the soft into hard, the rocks into spring wells, and the spring wells into rocks".

This phrase I took from the fairy tale [Billy Beg and his bull.](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/68/fairy-tales-and-other-traditional-stories/4857/billy-beg-and-his-bull/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a creative way of expressing the energy they had, and the transformation they could accomplish, or perhaps the fun they were having, or something like that.

The second part of each pair is the opposite of the first, and makes no sense. You can’t knock soft ground into hard, or turn a spring well back into just a rock.

It would be like describing the weather by saying something like, the rain was falling down hard, and falling up even harder, and by that meaning, it was really raining hard!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

It is not an idiom.  Its meaning comes from the meaning of the words.

The two bulls are fighting so hard that they break up the hard ground making it soft!  (this is exaggeration)  In fact they are fighting so hard that they trample the soft ground and make it hard!

They turned rocks into springs (where water comes from) and turned springs into rocks!

There is an element of joke here. There is the comic reversal and exaggeration. But there is no special meaning.